# How to do update multiple docs based on a query in one round trip in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Imagine you have a collection with documents as follows:

```
{
    "_id": "SOME_MONGO_ID",
    "rank": 1
}
```

And given an _id want to update increment all the documents with rank higher than it.

If I know the rank I can use UpdateMany to increment the ranks higher than it using a filter. However that would require two round trips one to get the rank and another to do the update many.

Is it possible to use a pipeline to lookup the rank and then do the update in one round trip?

I'm using the c# mongodb driver.

This needs to work inside a transaction so we can't use '$merge'

Comment: I didn't benchmark, but 2 "direct roundtrips" must be more efficient than a single "lookup journey", especially on larger collections. Mongo driver keeps a pool of open connections and overhead of making a query is not as expensive as in relational databases.

Comment: The mongo database is on the other side of the world (US) to the client (New Zealand), and the speed of light sucks, so round trips are painfully slow. NZ to US is 202.26ms per round trip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$lookup` with `$merge`.
If you expect few and small documents to return, you can use '$match' first, but it has the disadvantage of temporarily putting all of these updated docs in one document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: "SOME_MONGO_ID"}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      as: "updated",
      let: {thRank: "$rank"},
      pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {$gt: ["$rank", "$$thRank"]}}}]
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$updated"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$updated"}},
  {$project: {rank: {$add: ["$rank", incVal]}}},
  {$merge: {into: "collection"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8MoDq-buvad)

If you expect many documents (or large ones) to return, you can use `$lookup`  first:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      as: "ref_id",
      let: {doc_id: ObjectId("62fb40acd762c3e1150e0134")},
      pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$_id", "$$doc_id"]}}}]
    }
  },
  {$match: {$expr: {$gt: ["$rank", {$first: "$ref_id.rank"}]}}},
  {$unset: "ref_id"},
  {$project: {rank: {$add: ["$rank", incVal]}}},
  {$merge: {into: "collection"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - many docs](https://mongoplayground.net/p/II16fGqUF0V)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without merge: Command aggregate failed: $merge cannot be used in a transaction.

Comment: I can't think of a way without $lookup or `$setWindowFeild`, that will not group your entire collection, and they are both not allowed on update pipeline.